# ASP NET Call Server POST function returns null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I need to put the var numeroOrdem into server to do anothers functions, but in Call Server line the browser alerts that var numeroOrdem is null and I cannot proceed...
The first console.log line returns the data that i need, but in call server dont.

js:

```
function ApagarOrdem() {
        var r = confirm("Deseja Apagar Ordem de Serviço?");
        if (r == true) {
           let numeroOrdem = $("#idOSrr").val();
            console.log("OS: ", numeroOrdem);
            $("#carregaOrdem").css("display", "block");
            CallServer("POST", "/AjaxOrdemDeServico/ApagarOrdemAndPoligonos", { numeroOs: numeroOrdem },
                function (r) {
                    console.log("dentro da function")
                    if (r.Msg == "OK") {
                        console.log("dentro do if")
                        $('#CriarOS').modal('hide');

                        for (var i = 0; i < OS.length; i++) {
                            if (OS[i].NumOS == r.NumeroOs) {
                                OS[i].Remove();
                                $("#carregaOrdem").css("display", "none");
                                // OS[i].SetColorPoligono(r.OS_Return.Situacao);
                                //  OS[i].SetInfoWindowPoligono(r.OS_Return.NumeroOrdemServico, r.OS_Return.Situacao, r.OS_Return.Colaborador);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        else {

        }


    }
```

c#:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AppAuthorize(Modulos = new Modules[] { Modules.ORDEM_DE_SERVICO }, Permissoes = new Permissions[] { Permissions.REMOVER })]
        public ActionResult ApagarOrdemAndPoligonos(string numeroOs)
        {
            OrdemDeServico OrdemDeDB = UnitOfWork.OrdemDeServicoRepository.Get(or => or.NumeroOS == numeroOs).FirstOrDefault();
            if (OrdemDeDB != null)
            {
                var postesDb = UnitOfWork.PosteRepository.Get(idor => idor.IdOrdemDeServico == OrdemDeDB.IdOrdemDeServico).ToList();
                if (postesDb != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in postesDb)
                    {
                        item.IdOrdemDeServico = null;
                    }
                    UnitOfWork.Save();
                }

...
```

Comment: *"the browser alerts that var numeroOrdem is null"* - I don't see an "alert" in the code.  Can you clarify specifically what observation you are making?

Answer (score 0):

Create input object

```
`public class MyRequest
{
 public string  numeroOs {get;set:}
}`
```

Than change your API action to this

```
[HttpPost]
[AppAuthorize(Modulos = new Modules[] { Modules.ORDEM_DE_SERVICO }, Permissoes = new Permissions[] { Permissions.REMOVER })]
    public ActionResult ApagarOrdemAndPoligonos([FromBody]MyRequest request)
    {
     string numeroOs = request.request;
    /// code 
    }
```

Also I strongly recommend you to use PostMan for testing your API

Comment: why i can put the value into string numeroOs inside of MyRequest?

Comment: you should send valid JSON object